# How to detect that a different collection view cell has been selected?

Tags: uicollectionview, cell, avplayer, selecteditem

I am developing a music app whereby selecting a collection view cell plays a track - I wish for the cell, when selected/tapped, to play when first selected and to pause if selected/tapped again. I can effectively play and pause when the same cell is selected however the problem arises when I select a different cell. How do I seperate the logic so that I can find out that a new cell has been selected? (and can therefore play and pause another track). I've tried didSelectItemAt delegate method but that gets called every time the cell is selected and I cannot figure out how to detect whether a different cell has been selected or not.

The behaviour I am looking for in other words: cell 1 is tapped - track 1 plays, cell 1 is tapped again - track 1 pauses **OR** cell 1 is tapped - track 1 plays, cell 2 is tapped - track 2 plays.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I'm using Swift

[Visual representation of the App (a collection view where each cell is a seperate track)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJsLO.png)

**EDIT**

```
var currentTrack: Int!

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {  

          currentTrack = indexPath.item

   switch selected {
    case true:
        playAudio()
    case false: 
    //Trying to match the current indexPath against the selected cell so I can play and pause that one
     if currentTrack != indexPath.item {
         playAudio()
      } else {
        pause()
      }
    } 
} 

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  pointerArray[keys[indexPath.item]] = false
  print("Stop", keys[indexPath.item])

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user the indexPath to check which item is being selected. Im gonna use print as an example but you can add the code for playing the same way.

```
var songArray = ["SongOne", "SongTwo", "SongThree"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print(songArray[indexPath.item])

}
```

**EDIT**

In that case I would set a dictionary for each song and a pointer array to check whether the current track is playing or not. Also. if you want to stop the current track as the new one starts playing you can use the didDeselectItemAt function. Here is the code using both functions and print just as an example:

```
var songKeys = ["SongOne", "SongTwo", "SongThree"]
var songArray = ["SongOne" : false, "SongTwo" : false, "SongThree" : false]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    if songArray[songKeys[indexPath.item]] == false {
        songArray[songKeys[indexPath.item]] = true
        print("Playing", songKeys[indexPath.item])
        return
    }

    songArray[songKeys[indexPath.item]] = false
    print("Stop", songKeys[indexPath.item])

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    songArray[songKeys[indexPath.item]] = false
    print("Stop", songKeys[indexPath.item])

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - sorry I didn't articulate my problem well enough. I am trying to use the cell as a playback control of sorts - whereby selecting the cell will play (using the same approach as outlined in your answer) and then selecting it again will pause the audio. I can't seem to detect when a different cell has been selected (and therefore am able to pause and play that track) as didSelectItemAt is called every time the cell is selected.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using? It will help to understand what exactly is going on

Comment: Edited my question to include the code - Thanks for your time!

Comment: This works great thank you! (if I can ask a secondary question that would be great)... I am also programmatically selecting cells using next() or previous() functions however when programmatically selecting cells how can I capture the indexPath.item so that I can set each item to true or false in those respective functions? (when calling next() or previous() it selects the cell - therefore calling didSelectItemAt)

Comment: I've updated my question with some more code - The problem arises when I use the previous() function to select cells. Works fine when calling previous() but when I then select a cell after calling previous() the boolean is out of sync or something.

Comment: Yes, there are some problems with the implementation. I’ll try to guide you better but please ask in another question since they are two different subjects

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience - here is a link to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51273687/how-can-i-programmatically-select-uicollection-view-cells-and-update-a-pointer-a